# Search for facebook username in meteor

Tags: meteor

I have username of a facebook user.

I want to search for, whether the user already exists in my db or not if he already exists then return his "_id".

I tried like this

```
Meteor.users.find({"services.facebook.username":"xxx"})
```

I have users from google and password also
Is this works??

If yes how to return _id field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

put this code in server side,it will work

```
Meteor.users.findOne({"services.facebook.username":"xxx"},{fields: {'_id': 1}});
```